# Running python script as another user

Tags: python, linux

On a Linux box I want to run a Python script as another user.

I've already made a wrapper program in C++ that calls the script, since I've realized that the ownership of running the script is decided by the ownership of the python interpreter. After that I change the C++ program to a different user and run the C++ program.

This setup doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Do your other users not have the permissions to run `python`?

Comment: It's not a matter of running Python. The script needs to do things that need certain permissions. I don't want to give all users those permissions. The script is acting sort of like a controlled permissions giver, but first the script needs permissions itself...

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't change all of your environment variables. ie `~/` will still expand to `/home/old_user/`, which could cause some trouble further down the road.

Comment: @johannix I also came across with the exact problem. Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 16):

You can set the user with os.setuid(), and you can get the uid with pwd.
Like so:

```
>>> import pwd, os
>>> uid = pwd.getpwnam('root')[2]
>>> os.setuid(uid)
```

Obviously this only works if the user or executable has the permission to do so. Exactly how to set that up I don't know. Obviously it works if you are root. I think you may need to the the setuid flag on the Python executable, and that would leave a WHOPPING security hole. possible that's permittable if the user you setuid too is a dedicated restricted user that can't do anything except whatever you need to do.

Unix security, based on users and setuiding and stuff, is not very good or practical, and it's easy to leave big security holes. A more secure option is actually to do this client-server typish, so you have a demon that does everything, and the client talks to it. The demon can then run with a higher security than the users, but the users would have to give a name and password when they run the script, or identify themselves with some public/private key or somesuch.

Comment: I used this code in a script run from an Ubuntu init script, and it did NOT require the setuid bit on the python executable.

Comment: It works without setuid bit if you are root or sudo the script.

Answer (score 0):

Give those users the ability to `sudo su $dedicated_username` and tailor the permissions on your system so that `$dedicated_user` has sufficient, but not excessive, access.

Answer (score -1):

Use the command `sudo`.

In order to run a program as a user, the system must "authenticate" that user.

Obviously, `root` can run any program as any user, and any user can `su` to another user with a password.

The program `sudo` can be configured to allow a group of users to `sudo` a particular command as a particular user.

For example, you could create a group `scriptUsers` and a user `scriptRun`.  Then, configure `sudo` to let any user in `scriptUsers` become `scriptRun` ONLY to run your script.

Comment: Can't use sudo, since the script needs to be used by other people.