# how to impersonate user in python and use os.system

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am trying to impersonate a user in python and call a CMD command :

```
login('secondUser','123')
os.system("some CMD command ")
logout()
```

where log in and logout are functions that uses `win32api` to impersonate user.

The problem is that `os.system` does not execute the command as the impersonated user (`secondUser`), it executes the command as the user logged in to the system.

I use windows7 64x , and python 2.7

Is there a way to call a `CMD` command with an impersonated user?

Comment: Is this what you're after?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499268/running-python-script-as-another-user

Comment: @ChrisHarris the setuid sounds to be for Unix based systems only, doesn't it ?

Comment: yep , it's for unix not windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

os.system() surely is the wrong tool for the job. Try CreateProcess from the win32api module if you are using it anyway.

Comment: <b>win32process.CreateProcess(None, "whoami", None, None, True,create_flags, None, None, si)</b> ..using this line of code, how can i get the out put of the 'whoami' ?